# How to click on “Paste” option of empty text field after long press event in android appium automation in c#?

Tags: selenium, c#-4.0, appium, ui-automation

I have achieved the long press event on empty text field.
Than Paste option is coming but ui-automator is not showing any id for that and no specific key code for the paste option.So how to achieve this click event on "empty text field" for paste option using c#-selenium appium method for android.

I have tried following method.But it is giving 'Not Yet implemented'.

```
//namespcaces
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Interfaces;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.iOS;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.MultiTouch;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

public void pasteOperation(string elem){
AppiumWebElement element = FindElement(elem);
x = element.Location.X;
y = element.Location.Y;
new OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.MultiTouch.TouchAction(_driver).Press(element,x, y).Wait(2000).Release().Perform();

Dictionary keyEvent = new Dictionary();
keyEvent.Add("keycode", 50);
keyEvent.Add("metastate", 113);
_driver.ExecuteScript("mobile : keyevent", keyEvent);
}
```

I have also tried following link.
https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-can-i-click-paste-popup-to-paste-clipboard-data-in-android/3538

Comment: How did you achieve the copy feature?

Comment: Hi,If you have text inside the text field than just long press on text field than android specific copy,cut,select-all option dialog will come and then you can do other operation.But we have empty filled than that option is not there.Only Paste Button above the text box

Comment: Then enter some text and paste it. Pasted text would get override with the entered text.

Comment: I got the solution by touch action on the top of the that text box.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to click on "paste" option using touch action.

```
       /*
        * Perform Paste text to empty text input field
        * 
        * */
        public void PerformPasteTextToEmptyElement(string elem)
        {
            AppiumWebElement element = FindElement(elem);

            //Long press at center of empty text field for paste option
            PerformLongPressOnCenterofElement(element);

            //touch action on paste option above input field
            TouchAction action = new TouchAction(_driver);
            action.Press(element.Location.X + 30, element.Location.Y - 30).Wait(1000).Release().Perform();
        }

        /*
         * Perform Long Press action on Center of the element
         * 
         * */
        public void PerformLongPressOnCenterofElement(AppiumWebElement elem)
        {
            TouchAction action = new TouchAction(_driver);
            action.Press(elem).Wait(2000).Release().Perform();
        }
```